# Creating a login system using Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, cfml, cflogin

Im trying to create an admin area but cannot get a login system to work. I have three parts to this. The login.cfm page, login_action.cfm and the app.cfc.

When using this code, and try and login it only stays on the same page.

**Login.cfm**

```
<form name="fLogin" id="fLogin" action="<cfoutput>#FormAction#</cfoutput>" method="post">
  <label>Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" required>
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="Password" required>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="sub" value="Login">
</form>
```

**Login_action.cfm**

```
<cflogin idletimeout="1800">   

<!--- SETS the action page of the login form to whatever 
      page the user was trying to go to.  Since the login 
      will actually be processed in the application.cfm file 
      (or a template included in it), then the FORM action 
      is the page that will be loaded after the login has 
      been completed. --->    

<!--- IF there IS NOT a Query String passed in the URL, 
      only the requested page name is used ---> 

<cfif CGI.QUERY_STRING IS "">       
   <cfset FormAction = #CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#>    
<cfelse>        
   <cfset FormAction = "#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#?#CGI.QUERY_STRING#">    
</cfif>

<cfif not (isDefined("cookie.XXXX.email"))>
  <cfif NOT (IsDefined ("Form.username") AND IsDefined ("Form.Password"))>        
    <cfinclude template="login.cfm"> 
    <cfabort>
  <cfelse>
    <cfif IsDefined("Form.username")>
      <cfset username = #Form.username#>   
    </cfif>

    <CFQUERY NAME="login">            
      select * from t_admin where username = '#username#'      
    </CFQUERY>

    <cfif login.RecordCount gt 0>
      <cfif #Form.password# eq "#login.password#">
        <cfloginuser name="#username#" password="#login.password#" roles="admin">
        <cfcookie name="XXXX.email" value="#login.email#" expires="never" >
        <cfset session.userId = #login.id#>
      <cfelse>
        <cfset Invalid = "Yes">
        <cfinclude template="login.cfm">  
        <cfabort>
      </cfif> 
    </cfif>  
  </cfif>
<cfelse>
   <CFQUERY NAME="cookielogin">            
     select * from t_admin where email = '#cookie.XXX.email#'      
   </CFQUERY>

   <cfloginuser name="#cookielogin.email#" password="#cookielogin.password#" roles="admin">
   <cfset session.userId = #cookielogin.id#>
   <cfset session.email = #cookielogin.email#>
</cfif>

</cflogin>
```

and Application.cfc.

```
<cffunction name="OnRequestStart">
  <cfinclude template="login_action.cfm">
  <cfif isDefined ('cookie.XXXX.email')>
    <cfset session.email = cookie.XXXX.email>
  </cfif> 
</cffunction>
```

If anyone could help that'll be great thanks

Comment: You're storing plaintext passwords. Stop and get that fixed that before you do anything else.

Comment: Please format your code yourself next time. (If you want other people to read your code, you want to make sure that at the very least it looks nice.)

Comment: As to why you always stay on the same page: Use `<cfdump var="#form#">`, `<cfdump var="#session#">` etc. to find out.

Comment: @Tomalak When I use the cfdump:#form# it shows no information in the dump just :Struct Empty

Comment: That's why I said "etc.". There are only a few `<cfif>` statements that control the flow of execution. It should not be too hard to find out what variables contain what values at what times. This level of debugging really is your responsibility, even here on SO.

Comment: According to your SQL script, you are only using the `username`, to log a user in. Why even bother with a password?

Answer (score 9):

There are quite a lot of fundamental mistakes in this code.

- Don't build an URL with the query string that came from the browser. You cannot trust *anything* that comes from the browser, therefore you must not use anything without scrubbing it down. Things like this are asking for trouble:

  ```
  <cfset FormAction = "#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#?#CGI.QUERY_STRING#">
  ```
- Generally don't ever write anything to the HTML of your page that came from the user without properly sanitizing *and* HTML-encoding it. Use `HTMLEditFormat()` and `URLEncodedFormat()` extensively.
- Don't *ever* use user-supplied values to build an SQL string. There is `<cfqueryparam>`, use it. This is bad and wrong:

  ```
  select * from t_admin where username = '#username#'
  ```
- While we're at it: Don't ever use `select *` in production code.
- Don't ever store plain text passwords in a database. This is a big thing, you really must fix that before you do anything else. ColdFusion provides a number of hashing algorithms, use them (and read about salted hashes).
- Is the login form sent through HTTPS? (Everything in that application should probably be HTTPS, but the login form absolutely *must* be.)
- Login cookies should be marked as `secure` and `httponly` ([see](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/coldfusion-securing-apps.html)) to prevent session hijacking.
- Login cookies that expire never might be not a good idea. Depends.

Comment: Thanks for this, do you know where I can find out information on how to do these?

Comment: A search engine? You can find basic explanations of tags/functions at `cfdocs.org/<name>` - i.e. http://cfdocs.org/htmleditformat and http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam - then click the blue "CF" to get the official docs. For the other stuff, putting the relevant terms into the search box in the top right is likely to yield useful info, otherwise try [DuckDuckGo](http://ddg.gg) or [Google](http://google.com).

Comment: @SamAllen get a copy of ColdFusion Web Application Construction Kit. In Vol 3 there is a whole section on securing your applications.

Comment: Even the Adobe ColdFusion docs have a [section on securing applications](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e34.html).